# How to convert UTC to EST by taking care of daylight savings

Tags: ruby

I am pulling the following output from a website using an API call:

```
out_string += "Incident Created :" + nextOncall_result['incident']['created_at'].to_s + "\n"
```

`"created_at"` gives the time when an incident was created. The website is in UTC, and I want to convert it to EST by taking care to daylight savings.

Please help me. Please change the code if possible.

Comment: This is the output which i am getting                                                Incident Created :2018-04-14T19:25:04Z                                               as you can see it is in UTC and i want it in EST. Please help

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: I want the expected result like                                                        Incident Created :2018-04-14T03:25:04Z

Comment: in EST time zone

Comment: whenever any incidents raised in website it will be shown in EST because my profile timezone is EST and website in UTC i am getting the output using an API call but above output comes in UTC please help  @stephan

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/135g3ielF_YypsWJobSIjofrZZxnsnrTH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: _"I want [...] 2018-04-14T03:25:04Z"_ – Z means UTC. Was that a typo?

Comment: In above link you can see the incident created at 3:25 PM EST and output is in UTC 19:25 i want exact output how it is showed in the website please help on this

Comment: sorry it is typo error

Comment: .in_time_zone('EST') worked but it is not taking the actual time when the incident was created it takes the current EST time in my system because the incident created at 3:25 PM EST. EST time as of now is 4:36 AM

Comment: Instead of adding comments and pasting images, take some time to **edit your question** in order to clarify your problem. Explain what you are **trying to do**, describe your environment, **show your code** and **what you have tried** so far. Include some **example input** values and the corresponding **actual output** ("wrong") and the **expected output** ("correct") for each one.

Answer (score 0):

In rails you can do:

```
nextOncall_result['incident']['created_at'].in_time_zone('EST')
```

**UPD**

```
require 'tzinfo'
offset = TZInfo::Timezone.get('EST').current_period.offset.utc_total_offset
time_with_dst_in_utc = nextOncall_result['incident']['created_at'] + offset
res = time_with_dst_in_utc.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %m:%S')
```

Comment: I am not using ruby on rails please advise to do in Ruby

Comment: require 'date'
DateTime.parse(nextOncall_result['incident']['created_at'].to_s).new_offset('EST').to_s

Comment: Hi andriy-baran,                                                                                                        thanks for the code please can you help me to change the code along with daylight savings.

Comment: Please help on this

Comment: See docs http://www.rubydoc.info/github/tzinfo/tzinfo/TZInfo%2FTimezonePeriod%3Autc_total_offset

Comment: Sorry to ask you the above code which you provided is for daylight savings